# Ignoring spaces while counting String tokens

Tags: java, string, dictionary

I am working on a homework assignment for a class and I have solved almost all of it, but am struggling with one part.

For the assignment, we are supposed to write a program that will count the frequency of occurrence of letters in any given string and then print out a map of them to the console. I have written the program and it works almost correctly, but I cannot get the map to ignore whitespace. It seems to find two different kinds of whitespace as well, one that is the space between words and another that I cannot figure out.

I've tried `myString.replaceAll(" ", "");` and `myString.trim();` to try and eliminate the whitespace before counting the frequency of letters, but it still counts both types of whitespace each time.

Any insight or help is appreciated. I could turn it in like this, but I don't like half-assing projects. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class LetterFrequency {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {

      Map< String, Integer > myMap = new HashMap< String, Integer >(); 

      createMap( myMap ); 
      displayMap( myMap );
   } 


   private static void createMap( Map< String, Integer > map ) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ); 
      System.out.println( "Enter a string:" ); 
      String input = scanner.nextLine();

      System.out.println("String: "+input);

      String[] tokens = input.split("");


      for ( String token : tokens ) {
         String letter = token.toLowerCase();


         if ( map.containsKey( letter ) ) {
            int count = map.get( letter ); 
            map.put( letter, count + 1 );
         }
         else 
            map.put( letter, 1 );
      } 
   } 


   private static void displayMap( Map< String, Integer > map ) {      
      Set< String > keys = map.keySet(); 


      TreeSet< String > sortedKeys = new TreeSet< String >( keys );

      System.out.println( "\nMap contains:\nKey\t\tValue" );


      for ( String key : sortedKeys )
         System.out.printf( "%-10s%10s\n", key, map.get( key ) );

      System.out.printf( 
         "\nsize: %d\nisEmpty: %b\n", map.size(), map.isEmpty() );
   }
}
```

Comment: lets see your code that tries to replace whitespace in the string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.replaceAll` should work. Keep in mind that `String.replaceAll` returns a `String`. So you have to use the string it returns to perform the rest of your computation.

For instance, if you have:

```
String myString = "hello world";
myString.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

`myString` will still be "hello world"

You'd want:

```
String myNewString = myString.replaceAll(" ", "");
```

After which `myNewString` will have no spaces.

Also, you can simplify your character iteration by using

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++){
    char letter = input.charAt(i);
```

This will fix your additional "whitespace being counted" problem. This is because when you call `myString.split("")`, the first element in the returned list is "" (an empty string).

Comment: This was the issue. I didn't realize you had to assign a new String. Although, I am still getting one unexplained whitespace that is counted.

Comment: Use the iteration technique i pointed out in my response. I edited my answer by adding an explanation for why you're seeing an additional whitespace count.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `myString.split("\\s+");` to get rid of all whitespace and split at the same time.

As @Kshitij Mehta pointed out, make sure you use the return value of that method.  So your code would look like this:

```
  String input = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println("String: "+input);
  input = input.trim();
  String[] tokens = input.split("\\s+");
```

Comment: he will have to use it on all tokens which is a bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative to `String.replaceAll`: You can [filter your input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) to ignore any non-alphabetic characters before counting them (or filter your map similarly before printing the result). E.g.

```
  for ( String token : tokens ) {
     if (Character.isLetter(token)) {
        String letter = token.toLowerCase();

        ...
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [Character.isLetter(char c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) method to determine whether a character is really a letter.

Answer (score 0):

@Kshitij Mehta is correct.

Your problem is a combination of not removing whitespace by setting

```
input = input.replace(" ", "");
```

Also, your second problem was using `Strings` instead of `char` (and Character for your maps) to save the letters(which are characters). It was just the unexpected use of String for char that made java perform unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class M {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    s.toCharArray();
    String n = s.replaceAll(" ","");
    System.out.println(n.length());
  }
}
```

You can try this. I know you already did it. But I think it will help someone else.

Comment: What's the purpose of line "s.toCharArray();" when you're not assigning the return value to anything? See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray()